# Magento 2 How to Remove product information tabs

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, tabs

Please suggest how can we remove the "More Information" tabs from product 
details page

See : http://awesomescreenshot.com/0f765e4128

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN4YN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN4YN.png) Hello, How we remove More Information name ??? and shift the content left side ???

Comment: Not understand can you please send scrn short

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159429)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159432)

Answer (score 22):

You can use the following in your layout file to remove the "More Information" tab:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true" />
```

If you need to remove the "Details" tab:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 12):

When looking in /slippers.nl/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml you can see how it is added to the page.

```
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                ...
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="product/view/attributes.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                ...
            </block>
        </block>
```

You can see here the names of the elements you want to remove.
Use the following to only remove the description/details tab:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.description" remove="true" />
```

Use the following to only remove the attribues/information tab:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true" />
```

Use the following to remove the entire section/all tabs:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Can try via Layout XML

like

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
```

or some tabs - remove tab with reviews

```
<referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove="true"></referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want as well just to un-check the option "show on product detail page" for all attributes.

To do this for all attributes run a mysql query:

```
update catalog_eav_attribute set is_visible_on_front = 0
```

The advantage is, that you still can decide in the future to show single attributes and you do not need code modification.